# Extra text in `nav`

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and need to convert this vertical navigation to something horizontal and smaller:

[image]

I would like to achieve this by using two NAVs each with the section text prepended. Basically, like this:

> **Training:** Become Certified, Train Staff, Learn to Pack, Mentoring and Hands-on Training, NASMM FrontDoor Training
>
> **Grow Your Business:** Public Speaking 2.0, Presentations in a Box

I am using this code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li>HELLO</li>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

But get this result:

[image]

Is there a way to do this while having the HELLO (the section topic) show up properly?

Comment: Can you show your current css?

Comment: Without a complete code example is very difficult to help.

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/msp2qb56/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your list items to display inline-block like this they are being shown horizontally instead of vertically, you might want to add some additional margins and/or paddings to them.

```
.nav li{
    display: inline-block
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asturias/kccL6tsn/)

Comment: Looks great, thanks. And the matching Bootstrap style is: `padding:10px 15px`

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you put correct CSS code on

nav li a. {
}

But you need to put this code on

nav li {
}